# How to escape files containing special characters like -, or spaces

Tags: linux, bash, msys

The contents of a directory:

```
$ ls -l
total 122639
-rw-r--r-- 1 125578080 Aug 20 17:47 - Diana Krall, Stan Getz & Oscar Peterson.7z
drwxr-xr-x 4      4096 Aug 20 18:02 Java
```

I wish to use the `file` command in this directory, where a lot of various files are copied

```
$ file *
```

The result I expect:

```
$ file *
- Diana Krall, Stan Getz & Oscar Peterson.7z: 7-zip archive data, version 0.3
java: directory
```

The result I get:

```
$ file *
file: illegal option --
file: illegal option -- D
file: illegal option -- a
file: illegal option -- a
file: illegal option --
file: illegal option -- K
file: illegal option -- a
file: illegal option -- l
file: illegal option -- l
file: illegal option -- ,
file: illegal option --
file: illegal option -- S
file: illegal option -- t
file: illegal option -- a
file: illegal option --
file: illegal option -- G
Usage: file [-bchikLNnprsvz0] [--apple] [--mime-encoding] [--mime-type]
            [-e testname] [-F separator] [-f namefile] [-m magicfiles] file ...
       file -C [-m magicfiles]
       file [--help]
```

I can spell out the filenames and escape things manually, but I want to use `*`:

```
$ file -- -\ Diana\ Krall\,\ Stan\ Getz\ \&\ Oscar\ Peterson.7z
- Diana Krall, Stan Getz & Oscar Peterson.7z: 7-zip archive data, version 0.3

$ file java
java: directory
```

How can I escape or protect `*` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use just the following

```
file ./*
```

All is needed.

Comment: Simple, as expected ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can tell `file` (and most other Unix command line tools) to stop looking for option switches by passing them `--` as an argument.  Thus, the following will work:

```
file -- *
```

(Of course, val0x00ff's suggestion of `file ./*` will work too, but will cause the `./` to appear prepended to the file names in the output.)

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

`file -- *`

`--` Means end of options of command.
Because file command think `-` in file name is part of your option.